# refer to last available historical data

Tags: django, postgresql

In a django project backed by a postgresql db I have two models,:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class AssetHistory(models.Model):
    asset = models.ForeignKey('Asset', ...)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(...)
    value = models.IntegerField(...)
```

Periodically some data are added to AssetHistory for some specific asset.
What is the best practice to refer to the last value in AssetHistory for a specific asset?

I was thinking to add 2 extra fields in Asset model and update them when a new entry is added to AssetHistory

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(...)
    value = models.IntegerField(...)
```

but i'm not sure this is the best choice.

Comment: USE LATEST 
  AssetHistory.objects.filter(Asset=Asset_obj).latest('timestamp')

Comment: This is not really efficient. If i Need to retrive this value continouslly it's very expensive